# Finding the value of ${_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ 1/9\right)$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I need help finding the value of
$${_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ \frac{1}{9} \right)\tag1$$

Not in terms of elliptic functions.

---

I've tried many methods on this and have reduced it down to many forms, none of which have provided any help to me, however I think they may be of some use here.

We have the identity
$${_2F_1}\left(a,1-a;1;\ z\right)= P_{-a}(1-2z)$$
Which leads to $(1)$ being equal to 
$$\frac{2 \operatorname{K}({1/9})}{\pi}^*$$

Where $\operatorname{K}(x)$ is the [Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html). This is technically a closed form, but I would prefer to find a closed form not in terms of elliptic integrals - since elliptic integrals can be expressed in the form ${_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ x^2\right)$ this closed form feels awful circular.

It also seems to be equal to
$${_2F_1}\left(\frac14,\frac34;\ 1;\ 9/25 \right)\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$$

and many other equivalent but seemingly useless forms that can be computed using [(1)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4#iii) [(2)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8#E1)

I've gotten tantalizingly close but haven't been able to crack it. What is the closed form for this hypergeometric function, if there is one?

---

*Also, this is probably a very stupid question, but on both Wolfram Mathworld and Wikipedia they claim ${_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ k^2\right)=\operatorname{K}(k)$ which means $(1)$ should be equal to $\operatorname{K}(1/3)$ but Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica both seem to say ${_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ k\right)=\operatorname{K}(k)$

Comment: Note that  Mathematica uses the parameter convention for its elliptic integrals, and not the usual modulus. So to achieve $K(k)$ you'd type `EllipticK[k^2]`.

Answer (score 8):

This is not an answer but some hints which rather indicate that there is *no simple closed* formula for this expression.

> We can find an expression of ${_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{1}{9} \right)$ in terms of the central binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$.
>   Using D. Knuths notation of *[rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)* $x^{\overline{n}}=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$ and the notation for *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* $$(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!=2^nn!(2n-1)!!$$ we obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\overline{n}}&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{2}\cdots\left(\frac{1}{2}+(n-1)\right)
> =\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}\\
> \\
> 1^{\overline{n}}&=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots (1+(n-1))=n!
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> {_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{1}{9} \right)
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\overline{n}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\overline{n}}}{1^{\overline{n}}n!}
> \left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}\cdot\frac{1}{n!^2}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{1}{144^n}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   Wolfram alpha evaluates the  series with the square of the *[central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* (1) as
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{1}{144^n}=\frac{2}{\pi}K\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   with $K$ the *[complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html)* with parameter $k^2=\frac{1}{9}$.

$$ $$

> I did some recherche on (1) and found two related results.
>
> - In the paper *[Central    binomial coefficients](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/cbc.pdf)* by  S.Finch   we  find on   page $5$  a bunch  of  formulas   of series   containing the central binomial coefficients and precisely  one with $\binom{2n}{n}^2$ as numerator.
>     \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{1}{2^{4n}(2n+1)}=\frac{4G}{\pi}\tag{3}
>   \end{align*}
>     with $G$ *[Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)*.
>     Note that Catalan's  constant $G$ is
>     \begin{align*}
>   G=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1K(k)\,dk
>   \end{align*}
>     with $K(k)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}}$. So, there is no *simple* closed formula for (3).

Another interesting paper with series containing $\binom{2n}{n}^2$ in the numerator is

> - *[A certain series associated with Catalan's constant](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/sums/Csum.pdf)* by V. Adamchik. He considers the formula 
>     \begin{align*}
>   S(r)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2}{(n+r)16^n}=\frac{1}{r}{_3F_2}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},r;1,r+1;1\right)
>   \end{align*}
>     Starting  point is formula (11) in his paper which introduces a function $g(x,r)$ defined as
>     \begin{align*}
>   g(r,x)=x^{r-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{x^n}{16^n}=\frac{2}{\pi}x^{r-1}K(x)\qquad\qquad |x|<1
>   \end{align*}
>     Note that $g\left(1,\frac{1}{9}\right)$ is our formula (2). He continues integrating $g(r,x)$ in order to reach after some further investigations and calculations  $S(r)$ for certain $r$. Although it was not obvious for me, but maybe his proof could be adapted to attack formula (2).

---

To your last question: I'm astonished, too. I would also expect $K\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ according to the Wolfram page describing the *[Complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html)*. This notation seems to be quite common. We can read e.g. in section 3.2 of *[Special functions (Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521789885)* by G.E. Andrews et al.
\begin{align*}
K(k)=\frac{\pi}{2} {_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;k^2\right)
\end{align*}
When evaluating the LHS of (2) with Wolfram Alpha it returns the RHS and states as comment: $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind *with parameter $m=k^2$*.

This rather cryptic note from WA indicates  some weird notation convention.

Comment: @TreFox: Many thanks for granting the bounty! :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can [express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) it in terms of [arithmetic–geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean):
$$
{_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ \frac{1}{9} \right) = \frac{1}{\operatorname{agm}\left(1,\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)}.
$$

Comment: Good answer. For any practical purpose this is the best way to compute the value of this number

Comment: I agree. That can be written as $\frac{3}{\text{AGM}(2,4)}$, too.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still interesting I have found that 
$$
{_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ \frac{1}{9} \right)\tag1 =\frac{3}{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{9x-13x^2+8x^3-4x^4}}\;dx
$$
or alternatively from your representation $${_2F_1}\left(\frac14,\frac34;\ 1;\ 9/25 \right)\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$$ 
we have 
$$
{_2F_1}\left(\frac12,\frac12;\ 1;\ \frac{1}{9} \right)\tag1 =\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{2\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1-x)^{1/4}x^{3/4}\sqrt{25-36x+36x^2}}\;dx
$$