# Is there a known transformation between $_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;z\big)$ and $_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;z^2\big)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888516/finding-the-value-of-2f-1-left-frac12-frac12-1-1-9-right), the OP seeks a closed-form for,
$$A=\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\tfrac19\big)=1.02966\dots$$
Using the transformation,
$$\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;z\big) = \tfrac2{1+\sqrt{1-z}}\,_2F_1\Big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\big(\tfrac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{1+\sqrt{1-z}}\big)^2\Big)$$
or more generally ([DLMF 15.8.21](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8#iii)),
$$\,_2F_1\big(a,b;a-b+1;z\big) = (1+\sqrt{z})^{-2a}\,_2F_1\Big(a,a-b+\tfrac12;2a-2b+1;\tfrac{4\sqrt{z}}{(1+\sqrt{z})^2}\Big)$$
we can transform $A$ to,
$$A =6\times\frac{\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\color{blue}{(1-\sqrt2)^8}\big)}{(1+\sqrt2)^2}$$
However, it turns out that the following do have a closed-form,
$$\begin{aligned}
B&=\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\color{blue}{(1-\sqrt2)^4}\big)=1.00748\dots\\[2.0mm]
&=\frac{\big(1+\sqrt2\big)\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac14\big)}{2^{5/2}\,\pi^{3/2}}\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
C&=\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\color{blue}{(1-\sqrt2)^2}\big)=1.04760\dots\\[2.0mm]
&=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}\,\Gamma\big(\tfrac18\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac38\big)}{2^{9/4}\,\pi^{3/2}}\end{aligned}$$

> **Q:** So, is there a known transformation between $_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;z\big)$ and $_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;z^2\big)$?

Comment: $$\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;z\right)=\frac{2}{\pi} K(z)$$ with Mathematica notation. It follows that such a hypergeometric function can be computed through the AGM mean.

Comment: For instance, $$A = \frac{3}{\operatorname{AGM}(2,4)}.$$

Comment: What formula did you use to make the first transformation?

Comment: @TreFox: I've edited the post to include the transformation.

Comment: I think you already answered this question yourself. Suppose there was such a transformation, then the ratio $\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\color{blue}{(1-\sqrt2)^4}\big)/\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\color{blue}{(1-\sqrt2)^2}\big)$ would be algebraic, which in turn would mean that $\Gamma\big(\tfrac18\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac38\big)/\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac14\big)$ is algebraic, which is most probably not.

Comment: @Nemo: Actually, I don't know the answer. :) If you go to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066932/), there are transformations there that work for real $N$, but result in algebraic numbers only for integer $N>1$. I believe the DLMF also has transformations that incorporate gamma functions in the body.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know the only transformations that contain Gamma functions are three term transformations, which are not applicable to $F(a,a,2a;z)$. I think if one finds another pair $B'$ and $C'$ such that $B'/C'$ gives a ratio of Gamma functions different from $\Gamma\big(\tfrac18\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac38\big)/\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac14\big)$, this will show that there is no such transformation. Do you know any other pair of $B'$, $C'$ for $\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;z\big)$?