# Infinitely $more$ algebraic numbers $\gamma$ and $\delta$ for $_2F_1\left(a,b;\tfrac12;\gamma\right)=\delta$?

Tags: calculus, radicals, modular-forms, hypergeometric-function, conjectures

Given the *[Elliptic integral singular value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html)* $K(k_m)$, *Dedekind eta* $\eta(\tau)$, *j-function* $j(\tau)$, and *hypergeometric* $_2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)$ with $\color{brown}{a+b=c=\tfrac12}$.

**Conjecture:** "The proposed equalities below hold for real $N>1$, though for any *integer* $N>1$, then the hypergeometric function $_2F_1(z)$ and its argument $z$ are *algebraic numbers*."

---

> I. For $a=\tfrac14$ and $\tau=N\sqrt{-\color{blue}4}$

$$\begin{aligned}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac14;\tfrac12;\,(1-2w)^2\right)
&=\frac{N+1}{2}\frac{(1+\sqrt2)}{4\sqrt2}\frac{_2F_1\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\,w\right)}{\pi^{-1}\,K(k_\color{blue}4)}\\[2mm]
\end{aligned}\tag1$$
$$w=\frac{16}{16+\Big(\tfrac{\eta(\tau/4)}{\eta(\tau)}\Big)^8}$$

Example: If $N=2$ so $\tau=2\sqrt{-4}$, then,
$$_2F_1\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac14;\tfrac12;\,\tfrac{9\,(1-2\sqrt2)^2}{(1+\sqrt2)^4}\right)=\tfrac{3}{4\sqrt2}(1+\sqrt2)$$

---

> II. For $a=\tfrac16$ and $\tau=N\sqrt{-\color{blue}3}$

$$\begin{aligned}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac16,\tfrac13;\tfrac12;\,(1-2w)^2\right)
&=\frac{N+1}{2}\frac{1}{27^{1/4}}\frac{_2F_1\left(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;1;\,w\right)}{\pi^{-1}\,K(k_\color{blue}3)}\\[2mm]
\end{aligned}\tag2$$
$$w=\frac{27}{27+\Big(\tfrac{\eta(\tau/3)}{\eta(\tau)}\Big)^{12}}$$

Example: If $N=2$ so $\tau=2\sqrt{-3}$, then,
$$_2F_1\left(\tfrac16,\tfrac13;\tfrac12;\,\tfrac{25}{27}\right)=\tfrac{3\sqrt3}{4}$$

---

> III. For $a=\tfrac18$ and $\tau=N\sqrt{-\color{blue}2}$

$$\begin{aligned}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac18,\tfrac38;\tfrac12;\,(1-2w)^2\right)
&=\frac{N+1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}}{128^{1/4}}\frac{_2F_1\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34;1;\,w\right)}{\pi^{-1}\,K(k_\color{blue}2)}\\[2mm]
\end{aligned}\tag3$$
$$w=\frac{64}{64+\Big(\tfrac{\eta(\tau/2)}{\eta(\tau)}\Big)^{24}}$$

Example: If $N=3$ so $\tau=3\sqrt{-2}$, then,
$$_2F_1\left(\tfrac18,\tfrac38;\tfrac12;\tfrac{2400}{2401}\right)=\tfrac{2\sqrt7}{3}$$

---

> IV. For $a=\tfrac1{12}$ and $\tau=N\sqrt{-\color{blue}1}$

$$\begin{aligned}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac1{12},\tfrac5{12};\tfrac12;\,(1-2w)^2\right)
&=\frac{N+1}{2}\frac{1}{12^{1/4}}\frac{_2F_1\left(\tfrac16,\tfrac56;1;\,w\right)}{\pi^{-1}\,K(k_\color{blue}1)}\\[2mm]
\end{aligned}\tag4$$
$$\frac{12^3}{4w(1-w)} =j(\tau)$$

Example: If $N=2$ so $\tau=2\sqrt{-1}$, then,
$$_2F_1\left(\tfrac1{12},\tfrac5{12};\tfrac12;\tfrac{1323}{1331}\right)=\tfrac{3\,\sqrt[4]{11}}{4}$$

---

This is a highly compactified version of the results by Zucker and Joyce in "[*Special values of the hypergeometric series II, III*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231927689_Special_values_of_the_hypergeometric_series_III)" but I used a ***common form*** for the argument $z = (1-2w)^2$ as well as similar eta quotients to better illustrate their affinity. However, I only derived this empirically.

> **Q:** How do we rigorously prove the four conjectures?

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061175/how-to-show-an-infinite-number-of-algebraic-numbers-alpha-and-beta-for-2).