# Functions whose input is the same as the output?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, terminology, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Given the *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$ and complex number $\tau$. I came across these family of functions,

$${f_2(\tau)= \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34,1,\,1-\alpha_2\right)}{\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34,1,\,\alpha_2\right)}=\tau}$$

---

$${f_3(\tau)= \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac13,\tfrac23,1,\,1-\alpha_3\right)}{\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac13,\tfrac23,1,\,\alpha_3\right)}=\tau}$$

---

$${f_4(\tau)= \frac{i}{\sqrt{4}}\frac{\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,\,1-\alpha_4\right)}{\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,\,\alpha_4\right)}=\tau}$$

---

where,

$$\alpha_2 =\frac{64}{64+\Big(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\Big)^{24}},\quad
\alpha_3 =\frac{27}{27+\Big(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(3\tau)}\Big)^{12}},\quad
\alpha_4 =\frac{16}{16+\Big(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(4\tau)}\Big)^{8}},$$

So the input variable is $\tau$ and the output is also $\tau$. Presumably these are [*identity functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) $f(x)=x$?

**Q: What are other not-so-trivial examples of identity functions?**

P.S. There is a $f_1(\tau)$ using $\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac16,\tfrac56,1,\,\alpha_1\right)$ but  it uses the *j-function*, instead of the Dedekind eta function.

Comment: Essentially the same eta quotients are used in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066932/).

Comment: For your four equations, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Inverse_function